# How did they make these gun sound effects from the 1970's?

Tags: sound-effects, western

Gun sounds from old films often had a whining sound like an electric motor or a 500CC motorbike. What materials were used to record that sound?

Comment: Some hints from Ben Burt, but no mention of the whine - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQM7MOePhmU&feature=youtu.be Leone used 'a copy of a cannon sound recorded for Captain Blood'

Comment: Also ref: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/94049/why-do-old-gun-fight-scenes-sound-so-weird-and-cartoonish

Comment: Thanks. Tetsujin, I was reading that one previously while searching "what materials do they use for the motorbike sound"